# Computing : $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-1} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, indeterminate-forms

Can you please help me with this limit? I can´t use L'Hopital rule.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-1} $$

Comment: We can apply binomial expansion and then divide them ? Or substitute x as y^{-1}

Comment: @ADITYA It's unacceptable to [change the question that invalidates previous answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189).

Comment: Will remember that norm..

Comment: Please your limit is at $x=1$ or infinity? specify and quickly solve this issue

Comment: It is to 1, thus the 0/0 limit

Comment: Please see the comment I wrote to you below, @Impropio.  You asked this question. $x \to \infty$. Stick with it,  We can't read minds. You wrote it as a limit with $x \to \infty$, Folks answered. Period.  The question is a PSQ, lacking any context/effort.  If you decide to post another question, this time with $x \to 1$, then be sure to include, like you should edit here, the effort you've put into solving on your own.  This is not a homework-completion-service.  If you need help, then you need to show also that you're meeting us half way.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP seems to be doubtfully on the whether $x\to \infty$ or $x\to1$ I have included both answers:

---

If $x\to \infty$ then we have $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-1} =\lim_{x\to \infty}{\sqrt{4+{5\over x^2}}-{3\over x}\over \sqrt[3]{x}-{1\over x}}  =\lim_{x\to \infty}{\sqrt{4}\over \sqrt[3]{x}} = 0$$

---

And, if $x\to 1,$ then we have:

By definition of derivative at $x=1$ we have 
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5}-3}{x-1}\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x-1}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-1} = \left(\sqrt{4x^2+5}\right)'\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^4}\right)'}\Bigg|_{x=1} = 1$$

Since   $$\left(\sqrt{4x^2+5}\right)'\Bigg|_{x=1} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{4x^2+5}}\Bigg|_{x=1} = \frac{4}{3}$$

and $$\left(\sqrt[3]{x^4}\right)'\Bigg|_{x=1} = \frac{4}{3}x^{4/3-1}\Bigg|_{x=1} = \frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: This is the prohibited L'Hopital

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't rollback quick enough since I was searching for a suitable [meta post about changing question after getting answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189).  My apologies

Comment: @RossMillikan Where did I use Hospital

Comment: When you took the derivatives at the end of the first line

Answer (score 1):

Make the ratio of the high degree terms which gives here
$$
\frac{2x}{x^{4/3}} \underset{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
EDIT :

I will propose my way of doing things. You are studying the limit around $1$ then, makes it move to $0$. Let $x=1+h$ 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{4\left(1+h\right)^2+5}-3}{\sqrt[3]{1+h}-1}=\frac{\sqrt{8h+4h^2+9}-3}{\sqrt[3]{1+h}-1}
$$
First
$$
\sqrt{8h+4h^2+9}=3\sqrt{1+\frac{8}{9}h+\frac{4}{9}h^2}=3+\frac{8}{18}h+o\left(h\right)
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[3]{1+h}-1=1+\frac{h}{3}-1+o\left(h\right)=\frac{h}{3}+o\left(h\right)
$$
So

> $$
> \frac{\sqrt{4\left(1+h\right)^2+5}-3}{\sqrt[3]{1+h}-1}\underset{(0)}{=}\frac{3+\frac{8}{18}h+o\left(h\right)-3}{\frac{h}{3}+o\left(h\right)}\underset{h \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow}\frac{24}{18}=\frac{4}{3}
> $$

Then we conclude that

> $$
> \frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-1}\underset{x \rightarrow 1}{\rightarrow}\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: That's a shortcut.. But it's always valid..

Comment: I´m really sorry, the limit should've been to 1

Comment: @Impropio You can't edit your question after receiving an answer.

Comment: @amWhy See [this meta answer by our site mod](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189).  "As a rule a question should not be a moving target, and to alter it in such a way as to render existing answers wrong or even just incomplete is discouraged."

Comment: @improprio  But, if you edit, clearly designate, at the bottom,  below the original question (which ought to remain), using something in boldface, like: **Edit:** " I intended to ask....".  Better yet would be to keep the question you originally asked. Period, and accept an answer to the originally posted question. If you are still concerned about what happens when $x \to 1$, post that as a new question.  But don't post another question, whether as an edit here, or as a new question, without including **your own work**.  Else, like this question, it will qualify for closure as lacking context.

Comment: Please see my comment above, @GNUSupporter

Comment: @amWhy I *was* frustrated to see that such dramatic change of the question due to the existing solutions. After leaving this for a while, I cooled down and I gave this a second thought: including the intention in an edit while keeping the original version visible is an effective way.  This respects both the existing solutions and the new ones, so that one feels comfortable to "answer questions in the spirit in which they are asked".  However, this should be done in a reasonable delay after the question is first posted: within several minutes is ok, but not after a week. Where to draw the line?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the fraction as follows

$${\sqrt{4+{5\over x^2}}-{3\over x}\over \sqrt[3]{x}-{1\over x}}$$

And this has $0$ as limit at $+\infty$

At $1$ we have a $0/0$ indetermination. Many ways to solve, the most elementary being the conjugate radicals.

Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{4x^2+5}+3$. This yields

$${4(x^2-1)\over \sqrt[3]{x^4}-1}\cdot{1\over \sqrt{4x^2+5}+3}$$

We still have a $0/0$ indetermination in the first term of the product while the second has $1\over 6$ as limit at $1$.

To solve the indetermination we’re left with we need to use the identity $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. So we multiply both numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt[3]{x^4})^2+\sqrt[3]{x^4}+1$ to get:

$${4(x^2-1)\over \sqrt[3]{x^4}-1}={4(x^2-1)\cdot((\sqrt[3]{x^4})^2+\sqrt[3]{x^4}+1)\over x^4-1}=4{(\sqrt[3]{x^4})^2+\sqrt[3]{x^4}+1\over x^2+1}$$

And for this term the limit is $6$ when $x\to 1$ and so the limit we’re looking for is $6/6=1$

Comment: But we were asked for the limit as $x \to 1$

Comment: Question is changed or mistyped

Comment: @RossMillikan The 1st version is $x \to \infty$

Comment: It was a mistake and I would really want the answer to 1. I've tryed making another post but I have to wait 20 minutes.

Comment: @RossMillikan One shouldn't [chnage the question after receiving an answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189).  Atmos had already typed his answer (with +1 score), then OP changed the quesiton to $\to 1$.  I found this unacceptable

Comment: I can delete my post if it is the problem. ^^

Comment: @Atmos just add for x tending to 1 part?

Comment: Hope it is all good now ^^

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use that
$$a^2 - b^2 = (a - b)(a + b)$$
and
$$a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2).$$